# Updating firebase database timestamp value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, timestamp

I'm still trying to understand how firebase timestamp works. I discovered that when updating timestamp value in firebase the value keeps updating without stop like a timer or stopwatch causing app to freeze, or is it that time value cannot be replaced with new value later in the app once saved?

this is how i tried updating time in my app

```
mRootRef.child("Chat").child(mOtherUser).child(mCurrentUserId).child("timestamp").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
```

I need to update timestamp value for items in my database subsequently in my app because that is how they are sorted in my app.

Comment: It's very unclear to be what you're observing: *"the value keeps updating without stop like a video causing app to freeze"*.

Comment: i mean that it is updating constantly like a timer or stopwatch

Comment: That means you're updating it constantly.  That doesn't happen by default.

Comment: how can i update once

Comment: The code you're showing will do that.  We don't have enough information to know why this is happening.  You'll have to make an attempt to debug this and add more information to the question.

Comment: I am very much confused as to why this is happening. could it be because it is a long value?

Answer (score 0):

```
postsMap.put("timestamp", GlobalVarables.timeStamp);

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    GlobalVarables.timeStamp= String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
}
```

this how i fixed my i removed `ServerValue.Timestamp` and replace it with `System.currentTimeMillis()` then created a  `GlobalVarables` class to hold the value and then call it during the mapping.